# JVM Cucumber Report

Tags: javascript, java, cucumber-jvm

Well  I am working on a frame work  created by some one else .  I have make that frame work functional right now  its generating reports  in html and json format. Now I wanted to  generate cucumber jvm report .  I did some research and figure out that  in order to generate this report  I have to create a maven project and make sure all of its functionality are working perfect so I have crated a maven project by  your  user friendly  you tube video .  From command prompt I am able to run all of mavens phases :  example validate compile test  verify .....

How ever I am not able to use mvn install ... also when i try mvn clean  and after that try to run my test cases i am getting a error no class found ?  can you please help and  solve this problam.
I am sharing my  pom and runner file  please give me some feed back how to solve this issue many thanks .....  Marit  where can I share pom with you ?

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and see if you can reformat your question better. If possible, provide location for source code so others can download and try it. Also, I would not ask members to *help fix the issue*, but rather for specific help on on what is broken. It's more actionable.

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml? From the error message, it looks like you are telling maven to generate a report and have specified something that is not a valid Maven lifecycle phase (the valid ones are listed). Which reporter plugin are you using? Are you using java or javascript?